# JsonSlurper float precision issue

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have a file with some data and configuration parameters that i need to change before I use it as body data for POST rest call.

So I am using slurper to get the configuration value

```
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def inputFile = new File("file.json")
def parsedInput = slurper.parse(inputFile)
```

Then I change the desired configuration parameter

```
parsedInput.config.id = 1
```

And then modified input file is written to the temporary file

```
def tempFile = new File("temp.json")
tempFile.write(JsonOutput.toJson(parsedInput))
```

I was quite surprised when I realized that the output file is three times larger than the input. I have checked the content and it looks like slurper changed the float precision.

Before modification

```
0.145,
0.144,
0.145,
```

After modification

```
0.1459999999999999908961711980737163685262203216552734375, 
0.1449999999999999900079927783735911361873149871826171875, 
0.1459999999999999908961711980737163685262203216552734375
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT 1: added some input data

http://wklej.org/hash/4de6639a5bf/txt/

Comment: Do you have some example input json?

Comment: Added link to the input file

Comment: @user2847328 Seriously, that's the best example you could come up with?  A massive massive file?  Four lines pasted here that demonstrated the problem would have been better than Megs of off-site json which will probably no longer be there when someone else has the same issue later on and finds this question...

Comment: This is the actual file I am using in my script, I have just removed some data that is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

check your groovy version, should be fixed by the end of 2011 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5129)

Comment: I am using groovy-2.4.5

Comment: @user2847238 check the type, whether it is BigDecimal or Double